# Intuitive explanation of Poisson distribution

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, gamma-function, poisson-distribution

I've seen the formula most commonly derived as a *continuum* generalization of a binomial random variable with large $n$, small $p$ and finite $\lambda = np$ yielding

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \binom{n}{x} p^x(1-p)^{n-x} = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda ^ x}{x!}$$

It follows, from this derivation, that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty } = (1-p)^{n-x} = e^{-\lambda}$$ yields the probability of failing infinitely many times when the success rate is $\lambda$.

However, from this approach, I could not grok the remaining term

$$\frac { \lambda ^ x } {x!} $$

---

### Question

What insightful derivations (perhaps, from generalizations) of the Poisson random variable exist which leaves an intuition for each of the terms?

---

### My Answer:

My answer, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2727388/338817 comes from geometric approach to Gamma function intuition (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1651961/338817) which I quote:

> Note that $\frac{t^n}{n!}$ is the volume of the set
>   $S_t=\{(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n)\in\mathbb R^{n}\mid t_i\geq 0\text{ and } t_1+t_2+\cdots+t_n\leq t\}$

Comment: So you specifically want a sort of "combinatorial" interpretation of the expression $e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$, rather than just any intuitive explanation of the Poisson distribution?

Comment: @JackM, any **precise** intuition will help, not necessarily combinatorial

Comment: You may find [my explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088111/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-exponential-distribution/2476526#2476526) of the exponential distribution inspiring. The connection to the Poisson is that both the ED and PD are connected to the Poisson process - in the language of the linked answer, the Poisson is the distribution of the *number* of births in a given interval of time. This is a very different approach to the "limit of binomials" approach, however.

Comment: You say you want "precise intuition". That seems a bit contradictory; if an explanation is completely precise, then it's a proof (which may or may not be intuitive, depending on the reader).

Comment: @tparker https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/, I think seek a post-rigorous understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $k$ *successes* occur in an interval $[0, t)$ and let their times be given by the $k$-tuple $(t_1, \dots, t_k), t_i \leq t$.

The set of events where exactly $n$ successes occur can be measured as
$$ \int_0^{t} \int_0^{t - x_1} \cdots \int_0^{ t - \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} x_i } \int_0^{ t - \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i } dx_n dx_{n-1} dx_{n-2} \dots dx_2 dx_1 = \frac{ t^n } { n! }$$

Importantly, the size of the sample space of all events is measured by considering the size of all possible $k$-tuples, $\forall n \geq 0$:

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{ t^k }{ k! } = e^t$$

Taking the ratio of these size of these sets yields the probability that $n$ events occur in the interval $[0, t)$.

$$\boxed{ P \{ X = n \} = e^{-t} \frac{ t^n }{ n! } }$$

**Note:**

More generally, the event rate can be made non-homogeneous with a scalar function $\lambda(t)$. When the rate is constant for all time, i.e, $\lambda(t) = \lambda$, we write

$$P(X = n) = e^{-\lambda t}\frac{ (\lambda t)^n } { n! }$$

Letting $t = 1$ gives the process on a unit time interval, scaled by $\lambda$. Although we're really interested in $[0, 1)$, it's really as if we're looking at the interval $[0, \lambda)$.

Answer (score 6):

Since you asked for an intuition, and there are many online derivations of the pdf of the Poisson distribution (e.g. [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/book/export/html/54) or [here](https://youtu.be/yR0hX7C1pYU)), which already follow a mathematically strict sequence, I'm giving it a shot at looking at it almost as a mnemonic construction.

So the pdf is

$$f_X(x=k)=\frac{\lambda^k\mathrm e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$

What about thinking of the Poisson parameter $\lambda$ as somewhat reflecting the odds of an event happening in any time period. After all, it is a rate (events/time period), and hence, the higher the rate, the more likely it will be that a certain number of events takes place in a given time period. Further, you already mention how the pdf of the Poisson is derived from the binomial, allowing $n$ to go to infinity; and in the binomial distribution, the expectation is $np,$ equal to $\lambda$ in the Poisson: $p=\frac{\lambda}{n}.$

Notice, for instance, that in the derivation of the pdf of the Poisson, $\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k$ is **precisely** introduced as the $p^k$ (the probability of $k$ successes) in the binomial pmf, $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$ The denominator $n^k$ is later eliminated as we calculate the limit $n\to\infty,$ and indeed, $\lambda^k$ is "left over" from this initial probability formula.

Now, in the pdf you have the term raised to the $k$ power, i.e. $\lambda^k$, and it makes intuitive sense, because each occurrence is independent from the preceding and subsequent. So if we are calculating the probability of $k$ iid events happening in a time period, we shouldn't be surprised to end up with $\underbrace{\lambda\cdot\lambda \cdots\lambda}_k=\lambda^k$.

Since these events are indistinguishable from each other, it is not surprising either that we have to prevent over-counting by dividing by the number of permutations of these events, $k!.$ This, in fact is the exact role of the term in the combinations formula of $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\color{blue}{k!}}.$

And for the term $e^{-\lambda}$ we could bring into play the inter-arrival time following an exponential distribution: as the rate $\lambda$ increases, the inter-arrival time decreases. We can think of this factor as decreasing the probability of a low $k$ number of events when the rate $\lambda$ factor is high.

Comment: @Antoni_Parellada, it doesn't make sense to think of $\lambda$ as a probability, because $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and also if $\lambda$ has units events/time, then what units would you through onto $p$, the probability of the event?

Comment: @jaslibra I’m not necessarily defending the analogy (which is great by the way, +1) but here’s something to consider: there’s a difference between $\lambda$ being a literal probability and being a *measure/indication* of a probability.

Comment: @jaslibra To consider $\lambda$ as a probability measure is **an atrocity** (committed by me after much hedging). I believe that was clearly and explicitly stated, not just in the opening remarks, but also in the careful introduction of the idea. I was shooting for an intuition, but if it doesn't help you, I'll delete the answer.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor, thanks for pointing that out. I'm looking for intuitive, but my intuition should still be **precise** in understanding exactly what $\lambda ^ k$ should represent.

Comment: @AntoniParellada You don't need to delete your answer. And an up-vote would be helpful if you think this deserves more attention

Comment: @jaslibra There is a ton of intuition built into the derivation from the binomial as $n$ tends to infinity. And you may very well be onto something; however, it is also possible that after you've gone through the process of segmenting the time period into infinitely many intervals, etc., etc., and arrive at the final formula, there isn't much room left, other than to accept the result.

Comment: My idea is that I shouldn't have to derive it from the binomial, the formula should be obvious immediately, just as is the binomial

Comment: @jaslibra Please take a look at my most recent edit... I just read your last comment... Well... I really don't see it as obvious, although it is rather intuitive when you follow the "story" behind the distribution. But let's wait and see what other answers come through. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You're basically there with your limit. The ratio of two factorials is the product of $x$ numbers from $n-x+1$ to $n$, so for $n\gg x$ the result is approximately $n^x$.

Comment: How does this make intuitive sense in the context of the probability?